# What do you call these "rolls" on old clothes?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Below is the picture of what I mean. So, I wanna know the name of these "rolls", what are they called? Pellets? Rolls?

As you can see, some people use razors or fabric shavers to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to merely comment, but Like 1006a says, it depends a lot on location, and if you have them, then google search for "depiller".

Comment: we used to call it lint,

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Those are commonly known as [***pills***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pill_(textile)), or *bobbles* in the UK, though other terms may be in use depending on location. From Wikipedia:

> A **pill**, colloquially known as a **bobble**, **fuzzball**, or **lint ball** is a small ball of fibers that forms on a piece of cloth. 'Pill' is also a verb for the formation of such balls.

As the Wikipedia article mentions, *pill* is also the verb form for this, and the form *pilling* is sometimes used for multiple pills together, as in:

> This sweater **pills** like crazy! I started out picking off individual **pills**, but I really need a shaver thing to get rid of all the **pilling**.

Comment: Interesting... I've more commonly heard it being described as lint... never heard of this pill thing before

Comment: @colond Pills are made of lint, but lint also takes other forms.

Comment: Bobble is the most common in British English (anecdotally)

Comment: @ColonD Never heard of "pill" either until I started reading Amazon reviews for clothing items.

Comment: I've always thought that the name "pill" came from the resemblance between the little spheres of lint and small tablets of medicine. OED dates "fabric pill" back to only the 1950s, while "pill" as a small round dollop of medicine, ammunition, or animal excrement is attested centuries earlier.

Comment: Also, I believe that [pill bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillidiidae) are named after this phenomenon

Comment: I’ve never heard of pill. Coming from England, I only know them as bobbles. As in ‘oh no! My jumper’s gone all bobbley in the dryer!’

Comment: @Jelila or other BrE speakers, is there a verb form of *bobble*? I'm thinking if that's clearly the most common term in the UK I should add that info to the answer, so folks don't have to look in the comments for it.

Comment: If you ‘bobble something’ you put bobbles on it. Eg, to bobble a hat. Means, put a pom pom or, multiple pompoms or ‘bobbles’ on top of the hat. To ‘bobble about’ - to move or wobble in a ‘concentric circles’ kind of way. ‘The alien craft appeared, bobbled about (or, just ‘bobbled on’) the horizon, then disappeared. To ‘bibble-bobble’ to move in a ‘concentric circles’ or ‘repeating overlapping circles’ kind of way - between two things - ‘we bibble-bobbled between Harrods and Selfridges all day, trying on all kinds of outfits’. It means to move like a fly, moving in random overlapping circles.

Comment: You could, if you want to ‘de-bobble a piece of fabric’. Just be careful we don’t think you are removing pom-poms from it. ‘I’m de-bobbling the burrs from this fabric’. ‘I’m de-bobbling the fluff from this fabric’.

Comment: Funnily, where I'm from in the UK we tend to call the things "bobbles" but still use "pilling" to describe the accumulation of them on clothing.

Comment: @Jelila I suspect the meaning of *bobble* for the motion you describe is separate from it being used for these. The meanings don’t seem very similar, and that meaning seems more like the American usage. In AmE, it isn’t used for these (they are pills, as the answer says), but *bobble* as a verb is pretty common. It means, roughly, *flailing to try to catch something*, a sort of accidental juggling. Very often used to describe athletes having difficulties catching a ball (e.g. in baseball).

Comment: +1.  There is a standard test methodology published by ASTM for pilling.  https://www.astm.org/Standards/D3512.htm

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty sure that's lint.

> Lint is the common name for visible accumulations of textile fibers
>   and other materials, usually found on and around clothing.
>   [Lint (Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(material))

Here are the before and after photos of a carpet after a lint remover has been used:

[Picture](https://mummypriscilla.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/img_41461.jpg)

> lint
>   1.Clinging bits of fiber and fluff; fuzz.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lint)

It's important to remember that lint can refer to this type of material found in various places, for example, pockets, carpets, clothes surfaces, even belly button (navel).
[Navel lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(material)#Navel_lint)

Wikipedia covers a lot of them.

So you may want to specify by saying clothes lint etc. Also, not all lint is created equal, if they take form of a particular shape, like balls, capsules, rolls etc, you can use different words.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88679/discussion-on-answer-by-zebrafish-what-do-you-call-these-rolls-on-old-clothes).

Answer (score 4):

In the UK I call them bobbles, "the clothes have gone bobbly."

and to double check I am not alone:

> https://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/bobble-remover

[cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bobble)

> **bobble** noun
>
> ​ uk (us pill) a small ball of thread that develops on clothing or furniture covered in cloth